# sort list in alphabetical order (with numbers preceding lowercase letters preceding uppercase letters

Tags: python, list, sorting, compare, reorderlist

I want to order string list strating from

```py
l = ['AAAA.html', 'aaa.html', 'index.html', 'diem', '1zz.html']
```

I want to have this output

```py
['1zz.html', 'aaa.html', 'diem', 'index.html', 'AAAA.html']
```

How to implement soluzion in python?

Answer (score 2):

Usual sort in python is:

> number, uppercase, lowercase.

You want

> number, lowercase, uppercase

You just need to use, as sorting key, the case-swapped input value:

```
>>> l = ['AAAA.html', 'aaa.html', 'index.html', 'diem', '1zz.html']
>>> sorted(l, key=str.swapcase)
['1zz.html', 'aaa.html', 'diem', 'index.html', 'AAAA.html']
```